# ViewModel location into sub-folder (XAML, namespace)

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, namespaces, viewmodel

Into MainWindow.xaml I have:

```
<Window x:Class="LayoutMVVM.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"

        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LayoutMVVM"
        xmlns:veiwmodels="clr-namespace:LayoutMVVM.ViewModels"        
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:LayoutMVVM.Views"

        Title="Layout" Height="750" Width="650">
```

Into Windows.Resources I'm binding dataContext:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="SettingsTemp" DataType="{x:Type veiwmodels:SettingsModel}">
            <views:SettingsView DataContext="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
```

But when my other model and view is located into sub-folder as below:

[image]

I can't do:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Name="OpenTemp" DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:Open.OpenModel}">
    <views:Open.OpenView DataContext="{Binding}" />
 </DataTemplate>
```

or LayoutMVVM.ViewModels.Open.OpenModel

or LayoutMVVM/ViewModels/Open/OpenModel

Comment: There is a typo `xmlns:veiwmodels` should be `xmlns:viewmodels`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add new one in header of control:

```
xmlns:veiwmodelsOpen="clr-namespace:LayoutMVVM.ViewModels.Open
```

or you can set namespace of OpenModel to *LayoutMVVM.ViewModels* (**not** *LayoutMVVM.ViewModels.Open*).

There is no other way, I think.

Comment: correct view things and it's working with your first answer

Comment: one more: LayoutMVVM.ViewModels -> in that case, it should be assign to  DataTemplate directly?

Comment: no, you declare *veiwmodels* in window xaml tag, so in DataTemplate you can write *DataType="{x:Type veiwmodels:OpenModel}"* (if the namespace of OpenModel is *LayoutMVVM.ViewModels*)